# arguments.callee.caller.this?

Tags: javascript

I'm 99.9% positive that this isn't possible, but there may be some obscure ecmascript function I don't know of in JS1.9 or something.

Does anyone know of any way to get the `this` object of the calling function?

Comment: I misunderstood the question, removed my answer. I'm pretty sure this is not possible and would be against most good programming practices. :) What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to validate `this === caller.this` to get truly private instance variables :)

Comment: That… seems like a… weird idea. What's wrong with *normal* private variables limited by scope?

Comment: I want private variables on prototype'd functions :)

Comment: `.prototype.foo = function () { var lookMaAPrivateVariable; }` :)

Comment: @deceze ... I want private ___instance___ variables accessible from within prototype'd functions.  Happy?

Comment: OT: I gave up on trying to limit access to functions etc. Private functions/properties should be documented properly and used accordingly. If other people use your code and change it so that it breaks, it's their problem, not yours.... that's just my opinion. Forcing something into a language that was not designed with this in mind just makes things complicated.

Comment: @Felix Kling - I mostly agree, just tinkering with something.  If I can get the line `this === caller.this` to work, I can make everything else work, but I don't think it's possible.  Hoping for an ingenious idea :)  Plenty of things have been forced into JS that it wasn't designed to do.

Comment: @cwolves: Curiosity and somehow going to the limits is never bad ;) Just don't waste your time too much and think about alternative ways...

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about either putting `fn.scope = this` as the first line in every function or checking to see if the calling function is in the current prototype chain.  You can by-pass both of those, but not accidentally.  I'm trying to prevent co-workers from modifying variables and then coming to me complaining that things don't work only for me to say "don't do this *points at code*"

Comment: @cwolves - then you are on the wrong track. A function's *this* has nothing to do with scope, it is an identifier that references an object (except in certain cases in ES5 strict mode). It can be set to any object by the call, so it tells you nothing about the function or execution context to which the *this* that references it belongs. Closures can mimic private members by using scope to limit access to variables, you can't do the same thing with public properties. If you show more of your code, you will get more specific comments.

Comment: @RobG - mis-phrasing.  `fn.this = this` (or `self`) would be more appropriate, though there are recursion issues in this case, so I may resort to either walking the prototype chain or wrapping every prototype'd function with a 1-line function unique to each instance (ick!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're really trying to do here is control access to your member variables and thus your question is really: *"How do I restrict access to member variables?"*, then maybe you would benefit from reading this article "[Private Members in Javascript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html)".  It's possible, but since it isn't a built-in language feature, it requires a particular style of coding your classes and methods to make it work.

I'm not an expert on this, but I think it uses a closure of the constructor to control access.  Methods declared inside the constructor will have access to instance variables declared in the constructor.  Any caller from outside the constructor will not (whether those other callers are other methods, derived class methods or outside callers).

Comment: Yeah, I know that, thanks.  I'm trying to restrict them and still have a prototypal object model.  I'm looking for some clever way to tell if the calling object is the same instance as the current object.  I wrote this about 5 years ago, FYI: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3600451/Javascript-Basics-Part-8.htm

Comment: Then, I'd suggest you rewrite your question to be what you're really trying to do!  You'd be a lot more likely to get useful help that way and we'd spend a lot less time trying to figure out what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: The question is what I'm trying to do.  I can re-write it and add tons of detail except that it's simpler if I leave it as-is since that is a more succinct representation of what I'm trying to do and requires less explanation for people to read :)